# Win Live Mail font size increase in Win 8

Tags: windows, fonts, gmail, windows-live-mail

How can I increase the font size for Windows Live Mail under Windows 8? I've tried everything I can think of!

Comment: Try these: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2601253 & http://email.about.com/od/outlookexpressrichedit/qt/Change_the_Default_Font_Face_and_Color_in_Windows_Live_Mail.htm

Comment: There are several versions of `Windows Live Mail ` what version exactly are you using?

Comment: Version 2011 (Build 15.4.3555.0308)